# How to auto refresh a token when user is active - Wso2 IS, API Manager

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am using Wso2 API Manager 1.9 and Wso2 IS 5.

I am generating token by

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=username@domain.com&password=password" -H "Authorization: Basic ZmtvZTdJNUVuME8yTVVQMnpHOERqV05SVXU
wYTpmM0cyNmlrbVpVTHlhUFplTHlaRTZYOHJLSHNh, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://10.234.31.152:8245/token
```

Response is

```
{
   "scope":"default",
   "token_type":"bearer",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "refresh_token":"42a354167211de45aca1b2ebacc27d24",
   "access_token":"266c3aabaad48a587a6b5145d4f5252"
}
```

Here the expiry of the token is 3600 seconds. (It can be configured.)

My requirement is:

1. Token should not be expired when the user is actively accessing the APIs,
2. Token should be expired if the user is idle for 3600 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Application which uses the API should handle the api expiration time.if token is expired when user accessing the API, then need to obtain new token using refresh token[1]

1. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Token+API#TokenAPI-RenewingaccesstokensRenewing

Answer (score 0):

Application should be handled that using refresh token.

Thanks
Isura